# Dynamic Indexing using Solr

Tags: mysql, solr, indexing, dataimporthandler

How to do dynamic indexing in solr 4.0 using DataimportHandler and MySQL database?
I have data-config.xml file with database information and query for indexing. Is there any way to index dynamically when database updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DIH provides the ability to perform [Delta imports](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Using_delta-import_command).
DIH will maintain the timestamp for the last successful builds.
SO if your database is maintaining the timestamp for the updated records, the delta query would take into account all the records updated after the the last build timestamp.
Its a way for Incrementally building for the Index.